# How do you resize the Divs on your page based on screen size?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am in the middle of completing a coding test. I want to change all my div sizes according to screen size. This is because my test does not look the same on my laptop than it looks on a mac computer monitor. On my small laptop all the divs look big, however on a mac computer monitor it appears to look decent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media queries or set width/height in % or vw/vh instead of px 
I hope that is the thing you are looking for...
Or maybe use framework like bootstrap or foundation

Comment: Right,  In terms of sizings `div`'s themselves you can set the height/width to % values of the parent container.  Alternatively see [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) on MDN

Answer (score 2):

Use vh.

[Refer Viewport sized typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Use `100vh` and `100vw` if you want full width and full height. Else change accordingly.

```
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width:100vh
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Chrome Developer Tools to check at what resolution you want to change the size of your div!

If you have a div:

```css
#bluebox {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="bluebox">
</div>
```

But, when the screen size is 480px wide you only want the div to be 25px X 25px you would do like this:

```css
#bluebox {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #bluebox {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bluebox">
</div>
```

This is done with media queries - which is very simple and standard.
I hope it helped!